# merge multiple data.frame by row in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, do.call

I would like to `merge` multiple `data.frame` in R using `row.names`, doing a full outer join.  For this I was hoping to do the following:

```
x = as.data.frame(t(data.frame(a=10, b=13, c=14)))
y = as.data.frame(t(data.frame(a=1, b=2)))
z = as.data.frame(t(data.frame(a=3, b=4, c=3, d=11)))
res = Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a,b,by="row.names",all=T), list(x,y,z))

Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(a, b, by = "row.names", all = T) :
  column name ‘Row.names’ is duplicated in the result
> res
  Row.names Row.names V1.x V1.y V1
    1         1         a   10    1 NA
    2         2         b   13    2 NA
    3         3         c   14   NA NA
    4         a      <NA>   NA   NA  3
    5         b      <NA>   NA   NA  4
    6         c      <NA>   NA   NA  3
    7         d      <NA>   NA   NA 11
```

What I was hoping to get would be:

```
    V1 V2 V3
  a 10 1  3
  b 13 2  4
  c 14 NA 3
  d NA NA 11
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works (up to some final column renaming):

```
res <- Reduce(function(a,b){
        ans <- merge(a,b,by="row.names",all=T)
        row.names(ans) <- ans[,"Row.names"]
        ans[,!names(ans) %in% "Row.names"]
        }, list(x,y,z))
```

Indeed:

```
> res
  V1.x V1.y V1
a   10    1  3
b   13    2  4
c   14   NA  3
d   NA   NA 11
```

What happens with a row join is that a column with the original rownames is added in the answer, which in turn does not contain row names:

```
> merge(x,y,by="row.names",all=T)
  Row.names V1.x V1.y
1         a   10    1
2         b   13    2
3         c   14   NA
```

This behavior is documented in `?merge` (under Value)

> If the matching involved row names, an extra character column called
>   Row.names is added at the left, and in all cases the result has
>   ‘automatic’ row names.

When `Reduce` tries to merge again,  it doesn't find any match unless the names are cleaned up manually.

Answer (score 2):

For continuity, this is not a clean solution but a workaround, I transform the list argument of 'Reduce' using `sapply`.

```
Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a,b,by=0,all=T),
                      sapply(list(x,y,z),rbind))[,-c(1,2)]
   x y.x y.y
1 10   1   3
2 13   2   4
3 14  NA   3
4 NA  NA  11
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(a, b, by = 0, all = T) :
  column name ‘Row.names’ is duplicated in the result
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I did not have much success with Reduce. given a list of data.frames (df.lst) and a list of suffixes (suff.lst) to change the names of identical columns, this is my solution (it's loop, I know it's ugly for R standards, but it works):

```
df.merg <- as.data.frame(df.lst[1])
colnames(df.merg)[-1] <- paste(colnames(df.merg)[-1],suff.lst[[1]],sep="")
for (i in 2:length(df.lst)) {
    df.i <- as.data.frame(df.lst[i])
    colnames(df.i)[-1] <- paste(colnames(df.i)[-1],suff.lst[[i]],sep="")
    df.merg <- merge(df.merg, df.i, by.x="",by.y="", all=T)
}
```